# Dealing with dynamic JSON field names in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to bring in some data (List of Entities) from an external API that looks like this:

```
{
"ResponseCode": 200,
"ResponseText": "OK",
"Data": {
    "ramco_purchaseordershipment": "ramco_purchaseordershipment",
    "ramco_ramco_paymentschedule_cobalt_duesoption": "ramco_ramco_paymentschedule_cobalt_duesoption"}}
```

and feed it into a for each statement to run each value as a variable into a second pipeline.

In the loop if I reference @item.ramco_purchaseordershipment I get a value the problem is that the field names are dynamic I want to do something like @item[0]. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you feed into the for-each?  It will only accept an array and your activity('myactivity').output.data is an object so you couldn't reference @item().ramco_etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.keys() to get the keys and iterate this to get the values.
like below:

let arr = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
let keys=Object.keys(arr) // arr[keys[0]] will return you value

below data will print all the values
let data =keys.map(key=>arr[key])
console.log(data) // [1,2,3]

Comment: Does this require an Azure Function to accomplish... I was trying to avoid that scenario if possible.